# Detecting coordinates of a template in OpenCV with Python

Tags: opencv, templates, location, coordinates, detect

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui as pag

#getting a small region as a screenshot
region = (460, 400, 600, 400)
pag.screenshot('da2.png', region = region)

#using that screenshot to detect where a template might be and saving the image
img_rgb = cv2.imread('da2.png')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.imread('player2.png',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.6335
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 0, 255), 25)

cv2.imshow('Detected',img_rgb)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imwrite('01.png',img_rgb)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What I'm trying to do is to detect other players in a game using screenshots and a player template. The problem is that I don't know how to get the coordinates of the place where the templates where detected.

I also came across to a program that does a clone out of my screen for a certain region in real-time

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2

def process_img(image):
    processed_img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    processed_img =  cv2.Canny(processed_img, threshold1 = 200, threshold2=300)
    return processed_img

def main():
    while True:
        screen =  np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(460,400,1140,920)))
        new_screen = process_img(screen)
        cv2.imshow('window', new_screen)
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
main()
```

I don't know how to use this code to detect the templates that might appear on the screen ...

Comment: Doesn't `for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):` tell you the coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Studying your original code...specifically this line:

```
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 0, 255), 25)
```

If you see a rectangle drawn in the image that you've read, then `pt` is the top left vertex of this rectangle and `(pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h)` is the bottom right vertex of this rectangle.

The convention is that (0,0) is located on the top-left corner of the image, and (img.cols,img.rows) is located on the bottom right corner.

To get the integral coordinates of a point `pt`, you can use the `pt.x` and `pt.y` objects